# How can I install bumblebee with trisquel?

Tags: linux, trisquel

tried to install bumblebee in Trisquel I typed

```
$ sudo apt-get install bumblebee
```

and the output

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package bumblebee is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'bumblebee' has no installation candidate
```

So how can I install bumblebee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bumblebee recommends the use of NVidia's drivers which are non-free. That's why it's not included in Trisquel's repositories.

Though using non-free software on a 100% free distribution is kind of pointless, you could try the [Bumblebee PPA](https://launchpad.net/~bumblebee/+archive/ubuntu/stable).

Nevertheless, I encourage you to replace your hardware parts with ones that respect your freedom.